# Monitoring standard output buffer and redirect to a string C++

Tags: c++, stdout, io-redirection

I have multiple .cpp files which are printing out and I want to redirect this to a string. The structure of my project is: a main file which calls the functions from another files and the another files. If I have one .cpp file it is easy with stringstream, but if there are multiple files how can I resolve that?

Main.cpp:

```
#include "Second.h"

int main() {
    std::string buffer = "First line";
    printOut(buffer);
    std::cout << "Hello world" << std::endl;
}
```

Second.h:

```
#include <string>

void printOut(std::string buffer);
```

Second.cpp

```
#include "Second.h"

void printOut(std::string buffer) {
    std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
}
```

In this case the string should look like this:

```
redirectedString = First line\nHello World\n
```

Comment: Please add how "it doesn't work".

Comment: Whatever you're trying to do, this is completely the wrong way to do it. What is the real problem are you trying to solve? No, not the one you're asking here, but the real problem for which you think this is the solution.

Comment: The real problem is I don't know how to check if something is in the output buffer and how to put grab it from there.

Comment: @J.Devero And you need to do this why? Logging?

Comment: The output of your own program/process or a different one? If it's a different one you can't change try redirecting the output to a file when you run it?

Answer (score 1):

Output to the standard streams can be intercepted by using a suitable stream buffer. For example:

```
void do_something_with(std::string const& s) {
    // ...
 }

struct basicbuf: std::streambuf {
    std::string buf;
    int_type overflow(int_type c) {
        if (c != traits_type::eof()) {
             this->buf.push_back(c);
        }
        return traits_type::not_eof(c);
    }
    int sync() {
         do_something_with(buf);
         buf.clear();
         return 0;
    }
};

int main() {
     basicbuf buf;
     std::streambuf* orig = std::cout.rdbuf(&buf);

     std::cout << "hello, world\n" << std::flush;
     std::cout.rdbuf(orig);
}
```

When using multiple threads you may want to use thread local buffers to avoid having data races. The called function would actively transfer the buffer to wherever it is needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it only works if you have one .cpp file. What if you have multiple .cpp files which are printing out?

Comment: @J.Devero Why do you think it works only for one .cpp file?

Comment: I tried it and only contains which is printed out in main.cpp

Comment: @J.Devero: that seems unlikely. Did you redirect the output before you called another function? Is the output printed when it isn't redirected? There _is_ a chance that the redirevtion doesn't work if the other function is located in another shared object (`.dll`): each shared object may have it own standard C++ library.

Comment: Yes, I redirect before the function is called and the output it is printed when isn't redirected. I think think that is the problem, because the declaration of the function is located in a .dll. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @J.Devero: did you flush the stream after the output was done? The function is only called when there is an explicit flush, e.g., using `std::cout << std::flush;`.

Comment: I inserted this code: std::cout << std::unitbuf; that flushs the buffer after every output

Comment: @J.Devero: I don't see any reason why it doesn't work. Can you produce a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

Comment: @J.Devero: it seems you try to put the SSCCE into a comment - you may be better off putting it, e.g., on [ideone](http://ideone.com/), [cppsh](http://cpp.sh/), or something like that... (even if these one-file examples may not reproduce the problem).

Comment: @J.Devero: if you printed `text` after restoring the original stream buffer (`std::cout.rdbuf(oldbuf);`) it should show `First line\nHello world\n`. I see that there _are_ some DLL related declarations: if you build `Second.cpp` into a DLL which is dynamically linked it probably does **not** work because DLLs get their own copy of the standard C++ library.

Comment: Here are the files:
Main.cpp: http://cpp.sh/6k2g
Second.h: http://cpp.sh/2mhbu
Second.cpp: http://cpp.sh/4jahn

Comment: @DietmarKühl: is there any solution to solve this DLL problem?

Comment: @J.Devero: I'm not a Windows developer and I don't really know what can and/or can't be done across different DLLs. I'm actually somewhat surprised that passing a `std::string` through an `extern "C"` interface between different DLLs works to start with. Assuming the object layouts between the different standard libraries is identical I could imagine that calling a redirect function with a pointer the desired stream buffer for each of the DLLs could work. However, I have no experience doing that.